# Cordova File Transfer plugin giving an error - Ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to force download a file from a url. The App is build in angular + Ionic. I am using the plugin "Cordova file transfer".

Followed the steps shared in the url: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

But when i click on the download it gives me an error: ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined

Code for package.json file

```
<code>
{
  "name": "continuitas",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "continuitas: An Ionic project",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.7.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

**code:**

[image]

My Need here is to Download a file from a url in the ionic application.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file? and code which you have written so far?

Comment: Hey Sampath,
Thanks for your response.

I've updated the the code please check.

Comment: Oh.. This is `Ionic 1` no? Why you tagged it as `Ionic 2`?

Comment: My apologies for the misunderstanding, Could please you help me with the situation? I am new to the Ionic framework.

Comment: No issues.I have corrected it. But if you new to the Ionic why you started it using very old API? Why don't you use `Ionic 3`?

Comment: This project is completely developed by another developer. I Just have to add a download feature to it along with some pages.

Comment: Hmm.. OK.I haven't done any `Ionic 1` work.Started using `Ionic 2`.Hope someone else will help you.Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some missing injection in **ng-crodova.js** file itself so try to inject **'ngCordova.plugins.fileTransfer'** in your app module

```
angular.module('app.starter', ['ngCordova', 'ngCordova.plugins.fileTransfer'])
```